# How to mask asp.net MVC URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following URL:

> http://localhost/FolderB/Index

This goes to the following controller:

> /FolderB/HomeController.cs

I need to instead use this URL: http://localhost/SubComponent.

I'm not sure how that is done in asp.net MVC.  What is this type of masking called and where does the code live to accomplish it?

I have tried the following in RouteConfig.cs but it doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "SubComponent",
  url: "SubComponent",
  defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional},
  namespaces: new[] { "MyNamespace" }
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? If you are using MVC 5+ you can use the `RouteAttribute` to just add another route for `SubComponent`.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5.1.  So which ever version that uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of doing this would be to add another route in MVC that routes `SubComponent`.

You can add a route by looking for where your routes are wired up, which is usually either in `Global.asax.cs` or in a class called `RouteConfig` and adding your own route:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "SubComponent", url: "SubComponent/{id}", defaults: new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

The order which routes are added matters, so make sure this call to `MapRoute` occurs before all others.

And specify an area if you need to.

Comment: Nice - ordering of MapRoutes was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Latest Versions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

If you are using ASP.NET 3.5 ASP.NET Routing could be a good choice for you.

MSDN page: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Using it with ASP.NET MVC at ScottGu blog: 
[weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing)

Using it with ASP.NET 3.5: [www.techbubbles.com/aspnet/aspnet-35-url-routing/](http://www.techbubbles.com/aspnet/aspnet-35-url-routing/)

If your website runs under ASP.NET 2.0 Helicon ISAPI Rewrite could be a good choise for you. This is an IIS filter that redirects requests to your pages according to regex-based configuration file. They have a free version for one website.

Have a look at Helicon: [www.isapirewrite.com](http://www.isapirewrite.com)

Hope this helps. Good Luck

Comment: The ScottGu link seems to be an older version of MVC.  I don't believe all of that is definied in Global.asax.cs anymore.

Comment: Yes Space, but i was just referring it because i didn't know what version you were using, but the first link should give you some idea.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET MVC 5, use RouteAttribute. For older ASP.NET MVC version, you may have to resort to other open source (or your own custom) implementations e.g. https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting

Comment: Not sure how this works with RouteAttribute.  Shouldn't I be using RouteConfig?